# Bootstrap drop down not working in node.js project

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, drop-down-menu

My drop down initially work but I moved everything over to a node js project so I could handle user accounts. Now the drop down menus dont work. I've included the head and the drop down menu code. Most answers on the site have been fixed by properly linking jquery and bootstrap.

this is my head

```
<title> USC Elections </title>

<!-- Basic Angular App -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="controllers/mainController.js"></script> 
<script src="public/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/style.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link href="styles/one-page-wonder.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!-- Ugly Metadata -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
```

this is the drop down code - like a said above, it was working outside of node
http://pastie.org/9844268

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm getting errors loading all the javascript (jquery.js and bootstrap.min.js)

Comment: It looks like you're loading jquery.min.js from a valid googleapis link - what error is it throwing? Does app.js load? Is the path to bootstrap.min.js correct relative to your html (your directory structure probably changed when you moved to node)?

Comment: http://share.pho.to/8gIS5

Comment: those are the current errors

Comment: put `jquery.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Looks like there's a syntax error in app.js?

Comment: i fixed the errors in app.js and rearranged some of the script and link tags

Comment: i believe angular was messing with things